# Get HashSet as value from HashMap in Rust

Tags: rust, hashmap, hashset

How can I get the value of a HashMap, which is a HashSet in Rust?

Suppose I have ...

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct A {
    name: String,
}
 
fn main() {
    let x: HashMap<i32, HashSet<A>> = HashMap::new();
    let y: HashSet<A> = x.values().clone().collect();
 }
```

This gives me the following compiler error ...

*a value of type `HashSet<A>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&HashSet<A>`
the trait `FromIterator<&HashSet<A>>` is not implemented for `HashSet<A>`
the trait `FromIterator<T>` is implemented for `HashSet<T, S>`rustcE0277
iterator.rs(1832, 19): required by a bound in `collect`*

Comment: please check and let me know if you are not able to understand.

Comment: Its not clear what the desired behavior is, a `HashMap` holds *many* values organized by a key. Do you want the value (a `HashSet`) for a specific key (an `i32`) or do you want all values (many `HashSet`s) merged together into one `HashSet`?

Comment: @kmdreko, you asked me the right question and that one made me thinking what I really need. Actually I just wanted to have the HashMap of a key, which is trivial, but I had for some strange reason in my mind to need all HashSets merged together, what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be single `HashSet` it would be collection of `HashSet` that's why you are getting the error

```rs
let x: HashMap<i32, HashSet<A>> = HashMap::new();
let y: Vec<&HashSet<A>> = x.values().clone().collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9fc38497cd12f522d5945a40cd5da0c0)

If you want to create a single `HashSet<A>` from `HashMap<i32, HashSet<A>>` values one of doing is as below:

```rs
let z: HashSet<&A> = x.values().clone().fold(HashSet::new(), |mut accum, item| {
    accum.extend(item);
    accum
});
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6c229e1ef275113cd046cb9e823e9bda)

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. I was thinking in the wrong direction. Actually I just wanted to get out the HashSet or a copy of the HashSet, but I have no idea how to do that. Then I was thinking in the wrong direction regarding collection().

Comment: @Horowitzathome please check if the updated answer fulfil your need.

Comment: Yes, you gave me the right answers. Finally I thought in a complete wrong way and solved my problem in another way, but regarding what I have asked, you exactly hit both questions I had.

Comment: @Horowitzathome please can you add the way in my answer or create new answer so that it help others